# bootstrap 4.3.1 is not working offline and it's not showing navbar-toggler-icon

Tags: bootstrap-4.1.x

I need to build a website. I downloaded bootstrap all files then I linked  every file properly but I don't know It's not working. I don't know why  bootstrap 4.3.1 classes is not working properly. I am not see my navbar  toggler icon. why? please help me out and give me some instructions for using bootstrap 4.3.1 offline.

no background

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fa/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fixed.css">
<title>Nuno Theme</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
<!-- Start Home Section -->
<div id="home">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark fixed-top">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
<img src="images/nuno.png" alt="brand">
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"   data-target="#navbarResponsive">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
 <li class="nav-item">
 <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
 <a href="#course" class="nav-link">Course</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
 <a href="#features" class="nav-link">Features</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div><!-- End Contact Section -->

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used bootstrap 4.3.1 offline. but navbar-toggler-icon is not working.

Comment: Your icon is coming from `images/nuno.png`. Have you confirmed that the file `nuno.png` exists within a folder named `images`, where the `images` folder is in the same folder as the document? And have you tried refreshing the page / clearing the cache? Try `CTRL` + `ALT` + `R`.

Comment: I tried every way. but i don't understand how to solve this problem